# YouTube Android Player API deprecated in 2023 so how can Implement youtube player in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, youtubeplayer

I want to play youtube video inside viewpager, I ready documentation where mentioned that download the youtube android player api sk . But in the documentation
[youtube player documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player) showing it is deprecated so how can I implement this.

I want to play youtube video link in youtube playerview with play pause funtionality which is provided by default by youtube. and when it slide it will stop automatically.

[image: Youtube player image]

Want to implement like this :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube-Android-Player-Helper(YTPlayer)

Helper library for Android developers looking to add YouTube video playback in their applications via the iframe player in WebView

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.jaedongchicken:ytplayer:1.4.4'
}
```

https://github.com/JackDinealKIM/youtube-android-player-helper

Comment: Last commit 6 years ago?

Comment: But it still working fine @Michalsx

Answer (score 7):

As they say in the banner, you should use the IFramePlayer API inside a Webview.

Otherwise you can use this library (I am the owner): [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player). It uses the IFrame Player API inside a Webview but offers a native interface to it, so you can use Java/Kotlin to interact with the player.

Comment: Hi Mr.Soffritti, I wonder if I keep using Youtube android player api in my app after May, 1, will my app going to crash or the video player will broke? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what will happen with the official player once it's deprecated. I am not involved with it.

Comment: this player sometimes does not work I think it has some limited request to play a video

Comment: The player should work fine all the time. Feel free to open an issue on the GitHub project.

Comment: @PierfrancescoSoffritti I am using your iframePlayer now, works perfectly! I wonder if I could block ads when using iframePlayer

Comment: You shouldn't as that's against YouTube's terms of service. But if you really want to there should be a workaround in the lib's doc.

Comment: A simple library, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created an simple implementation using `iframe` webview as official player has been deprecated due to security vulnerabilities...

Here's sample link of a project

https://github.com/epegasus/YoutubePlayer

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube Android Player SDK (version 1.2.2) is no longer supported or maintained by YouTube. This SDK should not be used, due to [security vulnerabilities](https://www.cve.org/cverecord?id=CVE-2023-0460). Please use the YouTube [IFrame Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) API instead.

The SDK is no longer available for download. It will be fully deprecated on or after May 1, 2023.

You get the below error going forth -

[image]