# YouTubeStandalonePlayer is stopped working?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
activity,
getString(R.string.places_api_key),
videoCode, 0, true, false
).let {
startActivity(it)
}

This is stopped working. It shows an error while playing the video.

[image]

Comment: It was working fine before, But right now it is not working

Comment: You should link to which library you are using. Be aware that [YouTube Android Player API deprecated in 2023 so how can Implement youtube player in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75741191/295004)