# How to load youtube video url on my viewholder, from my dummy data

Tags: android, kotlin, video, android-viewholder, video-player

Can someone help me, how to load video on my viewholder ? it is possible or not ? if possible how to load

```
interface DummyMusicDataSource {
    fun getMusicData(context: Context): List<Music>
}

class DummyMusicDataSourceImpl() : DummyMusicDataSource {
    override fun getMusicData(context: Context): List<Music> {

        return mutableListOf(
            Music(
                title = "title",
                imgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryhanhxx/img_asset/main/IMG_MATERI_3.jpg",
                desc = context.getString(R.string.desc_materi_1),
                videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpwWeAsXnvA",
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

And this is my viewholder, how to show/play the video from url on video player on my project, someone help me :)

```
private fun showMusicData(music: Music?) {
        music?.apply {
            binding.ivImg.load(this.imgUrl) {
                crossfade(true)
            }
            // TODO: how to load youtube url video...
            binding.tvTitle.text = this.title
            binding.tvDesc.text = this.desc
        }
    }
```

Comment: check the following:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75741191/youtube-android-player-api-deprecated-in-2023-so-how-can-implement-youtube-playe

Comment: @ryhanhxx Your link is a webpage. **(1)** Use a `webView` to display it, **(2)** You might prefer to show the Youtube Player only, instead of showing the whole YT page (including comments, thumbnails, etc) . For that you need to create a custom HTML page that contains only the `<iframe>` part of the video player. PS: The custom page is just (HTML) text that you load into the webView (as a String, instead of using a link)